# GUI - C# PictureBox List reload in new form

Tags: c#, forms, list, picturebox

I have a form which creates a picturebox and inserts it in to a static list. I have another form which access the list and adds it to its controls with the following code:

```
foreach (var pb in Program.pbList)
{
    if (!this.Controls.Contains(pb))
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(pb);
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
            this.Refresh();
        }));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't show up on the new form.

Update:

```
PictureBox pBox = new PictureBox();
pBox.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width / 14, this.Size.Width / 12);
pBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
pBox.Visible = true;
pBox.Location = pb.Location;
this.Controls.Add(pBox);
this.Refresh();
```

But the form keeps refreshing and doesn't show my picturebox.

Extra:

```
public static List<PictureBox> pbList = new List<PictureBox>(); //Is in Program.cs
```

Code which adds to list:

```
PictureBox pBox = new PictureBox();
pBox.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width / 14, this.Size.Width / 12);
pBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
pBox.Visible = true;
pBox.Location = new Point(390, 100);
Program.pbList.Add(pBox);
this.Controls.Add(pBox);
```

Comment: you need to provide more code than that.. what does the other form look like ..? also can you show where and how pbList is defined.. and Program as well..

Comment: this.Invoke() is a very major code smell.  Probably means that you created the window on the wrong thread and cannot see it because that thread isn't pumping a message loop.  Whatever you might be doing, you probably have to invoke much earlier so the Form object is created on the UI thread.  And keep in mind that a control can have only one Parent so adding it to a new form removes it from the original form.

Comment: @StepCode show all relevant code what's preventing you from showing us where you have possibly gone wrong ..?

Comment: Just create a reference to that List in the other Form and you can pull them out and add them to that Form.. How to create a reference to any data items on another form? There are  ca.10 trillion posts about that right here..

Comment: I am it adds it to the list Program.pbList.Add(pBox);

Comment: If I remove invoke it gets an exception: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. Due to the this.Controls.Add I think.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to reuse controls since they will get disposed whenever the owning form gets disposed.

That will mean they will never render any more. Ever.

Construct a list of images and recreate the controls every time.

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry, I'm not really good with forms. I got an exception like that so instead I had the form run Hide() would that make a difference?

Comment: Hiding will not dispose the controls so yes, that would work a little. If you really want to reuse the image, create a picture box every time you open the new form.

Comment: OP did not say the the PBs are shown in the 1st Form, just created and put into a list..

Comment: On what thread are they created? Are they created on one form, added to it, and also to the list for reusing purposes?

Comment: Yes the list is so I can access it in another form.

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot do that. Because C# cannot reuse controls because the system would dump the control whenever the form gets dispose